# Selected text box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code that makes sure a text box is selected when my page loads. I have included my code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function box(query){
document.getElementById('query').focus();
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="box('query');">

<input id="query">

</body>
</html>
```

My question is; How can I make this script work without onload in my body tag?

I hope you can understand what I am trying to describe.

Thanks in advance, Callum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place it inside the closing `</body>` tag, so that the `query` element has loaded before it runs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

   <input id="query">

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function box(query){
         document.getElementById('query').focus();
      }
      box('query');
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a script tag at the bottom of the page, before the body tag. That way the DOM will (probably) have loaded and it will run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
runmyfunction(); </script>
```

By the time the browser gets there the DOM should have loaded.

It might not have loaded, though. You could use something like Jquery to run your script when the page/dom has loaded.